# Python - Print random number of lines from file

Tags: python, random

If file.txt contains:

```
appple
cheese
cake
tree
pie
```

Using this:

```
nameFile = ("/path/to/file.txt")
nameLines = open(nameFile).read().splitlines()
randomName = random.choice(nameLines)
```

This will only print 1 line from file.txt

How would I print 1-2 lines (randomly)?

**Example:**

first output = apple 
second output = cheesetree 
third output = piecake 
fourth output = cake

Comment: It seems to me that if you can call any line using an integer, then you could simply create that integer randomly, as well as hardcoding it.

Comment: ^ how would you do this?

Comment: Do you want each possibility to be equally likely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To produce more than one random number, use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample). You can randomize the sample size:

```
randomNames = random.sample(nameLines, random.randint(1, 2))
```

This gives you a *list* with either 1 or 2 items, picked as a random sample from the input.

Demo:

```
>>> import random
>>> nameLines = '''\
... apple
... cheese
... cake
... tree
... pie
... '''.splitlines()
>>> random.sample(nameLines, random.randint(1, 2))
['apple', 'cake']
>>> random.sample(nameLines, random.randint(1, 2))
['cheese']
```

Use `str.join()` to join the words together, if needed:

```
>>> ' '.join(random.sample(nameLines, random.randint(1, 2)))
'pie cake'
>>> ' '.join(random.sample(nameLines, random.randint(1, 2)))
'cake'
```

Comment: @user2611541: `print ''.join(randomNames)`

Comment: Any way to remove the [' ']? Thanks btw.

Answer (score 1):

You have two basic options, depending on (let's say you're in a two-line case) whether you want to pick *two random lines*, or *any random line twice*. That is, whether or not duplicates are allowed.

If you want to allow duplicates, you need to pick a [`randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) first, and then run the code you already have that many times. This is "pick a random line, a random number of times."

```
# print one or two random lines: possibly the same line twice!
for i in range(random.randint(1, 2)): # change the upper bound as desired
    print(random.choice(nameLines))
```

In the other case use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) and then print all the results. This is "pick a random number of discrete lines".

```
# print one or two distinct elements, chosen at random from nameLines
for line in random.sample(nameLines, random.randint(1, 2)):
    print(line)
```

---

Use the appropriate one for your use case!

Answer (score 1):

Do you want an even probability among all of the outputs?

Assuming order doesn't matter and `n` lines in the text file, this means you want to choose from `n + n(n-1)/2 = n(n+1)/2` different outcomes.  That is `(n+1) choose 2`.  If you set an empty value as the additional outcome, then you will get the correct distribution.

Thus:

```
nameFile = ("/path/to/file.txt")
nameLines = open(nameFile).read().splitlines()
nameLines.append("")
randomName = "".join(random.sample(nameLines, 2))
```

This is always choosing a `random.sample` of two, but one of the values could be the empty string that was added.  This will be as if you just choose one single value.

If you don't actually want an even distribution of all of the possible outcomes, then you would first want to choose if you want 1 or 2, then choose from the list of names accordingly.